# If I make a paypal donation page, do people need a paypal account to pay? Or can they just pay with a credit card?

Tags: paypal

If I set up a donation page in PayPal, do people paying need a paypal account? Or can they just enter their credit card at checkout and pay that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - **Accept donations made with credit cards**, debit cards, and PayPal right away.
> - **Donors don't need a PayPal account** to make their donations.

Source: [PayPal - Buttons for donations](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside)